# A featured meta post to list those we don't have room to feature

Tags: discussion

Every so often someone requests that another meta post be added to the permanently featured spot on the front page. This is then declined because there would then be less space for hot meta posts, which it is important to show to attract plenty of discussion.

Would it be a useful compromise to have a single featured meta post that acts as an index to all the posts we would like new users to see? This would replace the sandbox on the featured pane, so no space would be lost.

I'm imagining it linking to the sandbox and vital FAQs, but keeping the list of links short to improve the chances of new users seeing the most important ones.

Ideally the title would be something short that makes it immediately obvious that it is aimed at new users, and isn't something to ignore before posting questions or answers.

Comment: Title suggestion: `List of Featured Posts`

Comment: I think it would be a useful compromise, so long as this meta post is featured.

Comment: @mbomb007 I was hoping for something that wouldn't require clicking to know that it's important, and preferably something that specifies its content too. Possibly even simply "Sandbox and FAQs", but possibly "Please read before posting" or somewhere in between.

Comment: @SparklePony yes the point is to feature this instead of the sandbox.

Comment: Eh. Personally I don't see a need for it. There are so few daily posts on the meta that one can easily keep up with them. Maybe once Martin's [FAQ thingy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11913/a-proposal-to-combat-meta-bloat-the-big-consensus-freeze?noredirect=1&lq=1) gets done, we can simply feature that one instead of the Sandbox.

Comment: @mbomb007 That one should be limited in scope to answering rules, so it wouldn't be a good replacement. As for the title, something clear and sign-post-y like "Helpful information for new users" would probably be good (of course the actual content will also be useful to regulars, but they'll know what's actually behind the link... even with the current sandbox link, many new users ignore it, presumably because they don't know what's up with it and don't think it's relevant to them).

Comment: I think we could also remove the Sandbox, as it's already listed on the [Ask Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer That's only for people using the PPCG Design userscript. New users wouldn't be using it because they wouldn't know it exists.

Comment: @Mego I don't mean the "Propose Challenge" link the userscript generates, I mean that, if you read the "How to Ask" text on the right side of the screen, it includes the sandbox ("Please follow a [standard template](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1511) and post first in [the meta Sandbox](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140) for feedback.").

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh right, I forgot we got that text changed. Still though, the sandbox being featured helps remind users to look over challenges there and give feedback.

Comment: @Mego Maybe its only purpose is to draw attention to the Sandbox then, but I don't think it's functioning as it should in practice.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The Sandbox already doesn't get enough attention. What possible benefit could there be from removing one of the most prominent links to it?

Comment: @Mego so that we could replace it with something that links to it, and is more likely to get a click?