# What to do about a fluctuating consensus?

Tags: discussion

Currently on the defaults for IO [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/56656) is does not have enough positive votes to be instated.  At press time it has <s>+11-6</s> +18-9, defaults are required to have:

> 5 net votes and at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes.

However only a day ago this method was valid (If memory serves it was +10-2).  In fact it has changed at twice today as far as I can tell. And since this question has been asked it has continued to fluctuate between valid and invalid.  This has the strange consequence of making it a default for some questions but not others, depending on the time they were posted.

This would be bad enough but to make matters worse we can't know when it was a default and when it was not because voting records are not kept, or at least are not accessible.  We can only make guesses or try to remember.  And users with insufficient reputation can't even look at the votes to tell if it is a consensus.

What should we do about answers that are bordering between valid and invalid causing them to fluctuate between allowed and disallowed by default?

Comment: Personally I think it'll be better to say _around_ 50%,

Comment: @Downgoat I don't think that makes it any better, even if we move the bounds around the problem will still occur, the issue will occur whenever a default is right on the edge.

Comment: Somewhat tempted to close it as a duplicate of this: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11913/8478. That proposal is intended (among other things) to remedy situations like this. Once we have that one central post, changes can be made one meta question at a time and consolidated into the central policy resource. I'm sorry I keep delaying this, but I've been having some health issues recently and haven't been feeling up to it. I'll try to take care of it as soon as I'm feeling better.

Comment: @MartinEnder not a duplicate, but a link to it would work as a basis for an answer

Comment: It's not easy to find, but the timeline shows vote history down to the day (which should be sufficient). The one for that answer is found [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/11908/timeline).

Answer (score -1):

Use the consensus at the time of the challenge being posted on main. It is like the code-bowling rules versions. It may change but at the time it is what it is.