# Newer users can't view vote counts, therefore cannot view current site consensus

Tags: discussion, new-users, voting

So recently I've been reading through some [policy](/questions/tagged/policy) recently, and besides there being [a whole lot of them](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11913/a-proposal-to-combat-meta-bloat-the-big-consensus-freeze), I've noticed a problem. As I have less than 1k rep on the main community, I'm not an [established user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user), and so I don't have the ability to see up and down votes. While this generally isn't a problem over there, it also means that I can't see up and down votes over here. Some important [policy](/questions/tagged/policy) questions here include clauses such as this (taken from [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/96155)):

> A method is allowed if it has 5 net votes and at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes.

Without being able to see these votes, I can't tell if answers that may be [marginal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19360/96155) or have some [controversy in the comments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14972/96155) are actually valid to be used. In theory, I can't actually tell if *any* of the answers on there are valid policy or not. I also wouldn't even say that the I/O example is the most problematic out there. New users may be much more likely to run afoul of [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) if they think they've just come up with something clever that the community has been bored with for years, and they may get frustrated that they couldn't actually know if it was a loophole or not just because they don't have enough rep.

While I agree with the "twice as many upvotes as downvotes" clause idea in theory, it causes problems here. I think it makes most sense to allow all users to see up/down votes, if possible. I don't see a reason why that information would need to be hidden in any instance, and especially not on meta.

Answer (score 9):

<sub>Converting my deleted comment into an answer for more visibility</sub>

While this is a popular idea (and something I personally support), changing this isn't going to happen, but there is an easy way around it.

This is actually a common idea over on [Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com) (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts) from 2010 or [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/) from 2009). However, as outlined in both those posts, doing so is "expensive" for Stack Exchange and their system. This isn't going to be changed just for us.

Luckily for you (and other low-rep users) though, [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) Stackapps post contains a script (either a Greasemonkey script, a Chrome extension or whatever else your browser supports) that allows you to completely circumvent the reputation requirement and see the rep totals.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed this was something the communities would have some control over, seems odd that SE Inc won't do it due to server concerns. Could that Stackapps post could be linked to from those policy posts? I'd never even heard of Stackapps, much less that script.

Comment: @EthanChapman Unless you know of a specific policy post this would fall under, I reckon that being tagged with [new-users] should make it easy enough to find for anyone with the same thought path as you posting this question. It might fall under the [faq], but I'm not quire sure what the procedure for that would be (or really if it's this is such a common issue to merit being part of it)